# Time machine and RAID 5

Tags: time-machine

If my hard drive is 3TB and my RAID 5 network system (wdc PR4100) is 4 x 2TB will I have problems backing up the drive with time machine once the drive goes beyond  2TB (computer hard drive)? I ask this because it is my understanding that one of the 4 drives is used for parity and the other 3 drives are written across evenly.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like RAID 4 not RAID 5. Per the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels

RAID 4 is described as a block level stripe with a dedicated parity disk.

RAID 5's description is block-level striping with distributed parity.

(In many years of IT I've never seen an actual RAID 4 set in production use anywhere, ever.)

As far as Time Machine is concerned, the net result of the array is what it sees. It is the RAID controller's job to figure out how and where to store each block adding a level of transparency between the raw disks and the presented volume. In this case it should be around 6 GB of space, which should have no problem containing your 3.5 GB of data.